# Track player XP with Google play games service

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am trying to implement Google play game services in my Android game, and want to track XP for the current player.

What I want is that every time a player does something, he gets XP and then levels up according to XP.

I have found the `PlayerLevelInfo` and `PlayerLevel` classes in the API, but I can't seem to find a way to update those.. I have seen that XP are related to achievements, but is there a way to use this standalone?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Saved Games API](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/savedgames) to store XP and any other data specific to your game.  Play Game Services does not have built-in tracking of anything like 'XP', but cou also may be able to use Leaderboards or Achievements for this purpose.

Comment: It is strange that they do not have something dedicated to that, as some of the classes do mention XP and levels in their interfaces. Maybe it will exist in future versions.
I have decided to use a leaderboard for that, and calculate the level manually.

Comment: @Ran please mark this answer as correct, or provide your own answer and mark it as correct, so that the question is marked as resolved.

Comment: Unfortunately its not resolved, as all those solutions are just bypassing the problem.
Maybe Google will add more API in future releases.